# Python - Comparing 2 JSONs with variable key and value length

Tags: python, json

Trying to compare 2 JSON with variable fields length.

So far have this code, doing diff style JSON comparison:

```
def diffjson(found, expected):
    '''diff two json strings'''
    found = found.split()
    expected = expected.split()
    return difflist(
        found,
        expected,
        fromfile="found",
        tofile="expected",
        rstrip=True)

def difflist( fromlines, tolines, fromfile=None, tofile=None, quiet=False, addnl=None, rstrip=False ) :
    if rstrip :
        fromlines  = [ x.rstrip() for x in fromlines  if x != '' ]
        tolines    = [ x.rstrip() for x in tolines    if x != '' ]
    diff = difflib.unified_diff(fromlines, tolines, fromfile, tofile, n=5)
    diff = list(diff)
    if len(diff) :
        if not quiet :
            if addnl :
                for x in diff :
                    ret = ret + (x)
                    ret = ret + (addnl)
            else :
                ret = diff
        return ret
    else :
        return True
```

Borrowed from pandokia -https://github.com/spacetelescope/pandokia/blob/master/pandokia/helpers/filecomp.py

The output is for example:

```
\--- found +++ expected @@ -3364,11 +3364,11 @@ group global access"]},
"vjafUGJ9H0": {"260":-["test",+["us-east-1", null, "Not enabled", null, null,
```

So it means that 1st JSON is different from the other one by value "test".

My question is:

Is there a different way to compare JSON with variable key and value lengths?

i.e

Comparing:

```
{"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
```

with:

```
{"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Consider converting  your json into a python dictionary and then doing a comparision.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that also, here is my new question relating to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641788/python-show-only-modified-dictionary-key-value-while-comparing-dictionaries