# Python 2.7 - Show only modified dictionary key/value while comparing dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to compare two dictionaries with this code:

```
def dict_compare(d1, d2):
    d1_keys = set(d1.keys())
    d2_keys = set(d2.keys())
    intersect_keys = d1_keys.intersection(d2_keys)
    added = d1_keys - d2_keys
    removed = d2_keys - d1_keys
    modified = {o: (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
    same = set(o for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] == d2[o])
    return added, removed, modified, same

one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}

added, removed, modified, same = dict_compare(one,two)

print added
print removed
print modified
print same
```

However, it prints the modified key/values wrongly.

Output:

```
set([])
set([])
{'1iG5NDGVre': ({'118': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'tcp', '22', 'Red', '0.0.0.0/0']}, {'118': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'tcp', '22', 'Red', 'Blue', '0.0.0.0/0']})}
set([])
```

Any ideas how to correct it?

I just want that it prints "Blue" in modified.

**Update 1:**

Works but not when the dicts have different keys number i.e

```
one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"]},"119": ["test10","test11"]}
```

Will not show up test10 and test11 as added.

Dict could also have less keys, key can be also removed. Want to also cover that case.

Big thanks!

Comment: Are you always expecting that the dictionary value to be a list?

Comment: In your case `d1_keys == d2_keys`, which is ['1iG5NDGVre'], so there are no surprises.

Comment: @user1767754 Yes dictionary values will be a list. There can be however more dictionary key/values in other JSON than in the first one and vice versa. At Yakym I am new to Python, can you elaborate?

Comment: `added, removed, modified, same = dict_compare(one['1iG5NDGVre'],two['1iG5NDGVre'])` - you are comparing the Outer- 1-key Dict, not the inner ones.... they are identical - same key, no diffs, only 1 key. Voting to close as typo - also: beware of comparison for ref-params, they might contain the same data but the refs are different - so you get "differences" although values might compare equal - you still wont get what you are after if providing the inner ones though.

Comment: because you get the whole 118-value, not only "blue" which changed INSIDE 188 value-list

Comment: Thanks. This is tricky, especially for the beginner. Any chances for a pseudo code or sample code how to achieve this?

Comment: btw, you also need to realise that 'modified' here would also mean 'changes' eg where `test3` becomes `test4` and 'deletions' eg `Red` goes missing.

Comment: Yep, that's why it is quite a complicated task for a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare the list with the actual values with a *bitwise exclusive or* (`^`):

```
differences = set(one["1iG5NDGVre"]["118"]) ^ set(two["1iG5NDGVre"]["118"])
print differences
```

Comment: Tried this but get TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. Is this for Python 2.7?

Comment: I didn't realize you are actually comparing `list` and not `dict`. The error is raised caused you have nested `dict`/`list` in your main `dict`. Reviewed my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thanks for your help. However, how can I compare such dict/list creature ... the key from the dict will be random. Can you help on this? How can I generically compare such dict/list combination with another dict/list combination? My questions is also related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641447/python-comparing-2-jsons-with-variable-key-and-value-length?noredirect=1#comment88293092_50641447 when I compare two JSONs. Was advised to use it with dicts .... hence this question

Comment: If you know that this is the exaxt structure (`one` -> `dict` -> `dict` -> `list`) you can use something like `for mainkey in one:
    for subkey in one[mainkey]:
        print set(one[mainkey][subkey]) ^ set(two[mainkey][subkey])`. The concept is that you use the code in the answer to compare 2 lists, how you reach those lists depends on the structure that contains them

Comment: Thanks!!!! You are very helpful. It works when the one -> dict -> dict has the same amount of keys, but when it is different it does not show it up. See my Update 1:

Comment: What do you expect when the key number is different? With what will you compare the keys in excess?

Comment: If it is added,It should just show the whole list of excess key or if removed, it should also show the missing key whole list. My goal is to compare two dict -> dict (added, removed, modified). The second dict keys can be removed or added, lists in second dict could be modified. Does it make sense? Thanks!!!

Comment: Opened a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643953/python-2-7-dictionary-structure-dict-dict-with-a-list-in-it-comparison

Comment: Nice. Not near a PC now, going to check later