# Dictionary Structure (dict -> dict) with a list in it comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Have this dict -> dict -> list structure

Want to compare 2 structures of this kind.

```
one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
```

This code works well:

```
def compare(one,two):
    for mainkey in one:
        for subkey in one[mainkey]:
            return set(one[mainkey][subkey]) ^ set(two[mainkey][subkey])
```

However when dict -> dict have more or less keys it should be returned by a function that key was added or removed along with all list values.

Also if list was modified, it should be returned by the program that the list was modified.

Anybody can help on this?

It is pretty much used to compare two JSONs, I want to see when keys were removed, added or its values modified.

**Update 1:**

I am still learning Python

For this structure:

```
one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"]},"119": ["test10","test11"]}
```

It does not work.

It should print as output:

```
118 was modified. New values Blue. 119 was added with values test10 test11
```

and for these scenarios:

1.

```
one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": }
```

Should print as output:

```
118 was removed with values test1 test2 test3 tcp 22 Red 0.0.0.0/0
```

2.

```
one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"118": ["test100", "test200", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"]},"119": ["test10","test11"]}
```

Should print as output:

```
118 was modifed. New values test100 test200
```

I want to cover all possible cases. I do this as I said for JSON comparison.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please show us the input for which the code doesn't "work well", what output you get, and what you would like to get.

Comment: Thanks! Please see Update 1:. I spent several hours digging through code and experimenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some subkey to your dictionary to have an example for each case:

```
one = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"116": ["commonkey1", "commonkey2"], "118": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "0.0.0.0/0"],"117": ["test4", "test5", "test6", "tcp", "42", "Fucsia", "0.0.0.0/0"]}}
two = {"1iG5NDGVre": {"116": ["commonkey1", "commonkey2"], "118": ["test100", "test200", "test3", "tcp", "22", "Red", "Blue", "0.0.0.0/0"],"119": ["test10","test11"]}}
```

where:

- 116 is present in both, not modified
- 118 is present in both, modified
- 117 is present only in `one`
- 119 is present only in `two`

Then we iterate through our dictionary:

```
def compare(one,two):
    for mainkey in one:
        # Here we are iterating at "1iG5NDGVre" key level
        # We want to know the keys which has been added, removed, and modified
        # keys removed:
        for key in set(one[mainkey].keys()).difference(two[mainkey].keys()):
            print "{0} was removed. Removed values: {1}".format(key, one[mainkey][key])
        # keys added:
        for key in set(two[mainkey].keys()).difference(one[mainkey].keys()):
            print "{0} was added. Added values: {1}".format(key, two[mainkey][key])
        # keys modified
        for key in set(one[mainkey].keys()).intersection(two[mainkey].keys()):
            if set(one[mainkey][key]) ^ set(two[mainkey][key]): print("{0} was modified. New values {1}".format(key, set(one[mainkey][key]) ^ set(two[mainkey][key])))


compare(one,two)
# OUTPUT:
# 117 was removed. Removed values: ['test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'tcp', '42', 'Fucsia', '0.0.0.0/0']
# 119 was added. Added values: ['test10', 'test11']
# 118 was modified. New values set(['Blue', 'test1', 'test2', 'test100', 'test200'])
```

Here what's happening:

```
set(one[mainkey].keys()).difference(two[mainkey].keys()) # returns 117, aka what is present in 'one' but not in 'two'

set(two[mainkey].keys()).difference(one[mainkey].keys()) # returns 119, aka what is present in 'two' but not in 'one'

set(one[mainkey].keys()).intersection(two[mainkey].keys()) # returns 116, 118, aka keys present in both
```

notice that when we check element present in both, we always return something: an empty list `[]` if values are equal, or a list with the different values.

Also, we are using `sets`, which accept only unique values:

```
set(["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"]) # returns ("a", "b", "c").
```

this won't be a problem with the dictionaries, since the keys are also unique, but may create some problem with the lists. If you want to work around this problem, you can use [list comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension), which are also a good way to improve the previous code. I suggest you to also have a look on [Python set operation](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch16s03.html)

Comment: Great answer, comments and tips!

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(one,two):
    if set(one.keys()) != set(two.keys()):
        main_key_added = set(two.keys()) - set(one.keys())
        main_key_removed = set(one.keys()) - set(two.keys())
        print("The main key {} where added".format(main_key_added))
        print("The main key {} where removed".format(main_key_removed))
        return False

    for mainkey in one:
        if set(one[mainkey].keys()) != set(two[mainkey].keys()):
            second_key_added = set(two[mainkey].keys()) - set(one[mainkey].keys())
            second_key_removed = set(one[mainkey].keys()) - set(two[mainkey].keys())
            print("The second key {} where added for main key {}".format(second_key_added, mainkey))
            print("The second key {} where removed for main key".format(second_key_removed, mainkey))
            return False

        for subkey in one[mainkey]:
            if not set(one[mainkey][subkey]) ^ set(two[mainkey][subkey]):
                return False

    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to see added,removed, modified values. Not just True and False. See Update 1:

Comment: Updated my answer. Let you do the modified value

Comment: Thanks however, if you run your code on samples I gave in Update 1: you will see it does not work correctly. Got this output: `The main key set(['119']) where added The main key set([]) where removed False` where new key 119 was added with 2 new values